# How to label tics in axis on the basis of days of the week

Tags: gnuplot

I have some data that I want to feed to Gnuplot. The data comes in two columns, which are the values for the x and y axes, respectively. The first column (x axis) is an integer, which represents five-minute intervals - e.g. starting at 0, after 5 minutes the integer becomes 1, etc. In the second column (y axis) I have another integer.

This is a file that is constantly appended to - I am reading it every 5 minutes. I want to accomplish two things:

1. The plotted data should be updated dynamically, as I read the file.
2. I would like to label tics in the x axis with the names days of the week. The naming scheme should move over the days of the week in sequence (assuming that I started plotting my data on a Friday) cycling the names accordingly.

I am running this under Linux (Slackware 14.2), Gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3.

I currently have the following Gnuplot code:

```
    set terminal x11 size 1900, 800
    set term x11 1 noraise
    set xlabel "Days"
    set grid
    set xtics 1
    set ytics 1
    set yrange [0:40]
    set y2tics 1
    plot "Data1" using ($1/288):2 title "First Data Set" with lines, "Data2" using ($1/288):2 title "Second Data Set" with lines
    pause 60
    reread
```

The code above works fine, in that it prints out my data with tics every whole day (i.e. 288 5-minute intervals) and labels each tic as a sequential integer. I would like to change this so that those labels are, instead, days of the week, starting at Friday.

I have tried playing with 'set xdata', 'set timefmt', etc. but I am obviously misunderstanding how to use them. For example, I tried the following:

```
    set terminal x11 size 1900, 800
    set term x11 1 noraise
    set grid
    set xdata time
    set timefmt "%s"
    set format x "%A"
    set xtics 288
    set ytics 1
    set yrange [0:40]
    set y2tics 1
    plot "Data1" using 1:2 title "First Data Set" with lines, "Data2" using 1:2 title "Second Data Set" with lines
    pause 60
    reread
```

This plots and updates the data set all right, but the tics in the x axis are labeled 'Thursday' every time.

I finally found something that seems to work, but looks kind of ugly:

```
    set terminal x11 size 1900, 800
    set term x11 1 noraise
    set grid
    set xdtics
    set ytics 1
    set yrange [0:40]
    set y2tics 1
    f(x) = x/288 - (floor(x/288)/7)*7 + 5
    plot "Data1" using (f($1)):2 title "First Data Set" with lines, "Data2" using (f($1)):2 title "Second Data Set" with lines
    pause 60
    reread
```

'set xdtics' is what does the trick. As for the rest, the function definition just takes into account that 288 data points make up for one day, that the day of the week, which is the number of days mod 7, is computed as N - floor(N/7)*7 - I couldn't find a modulus operator to be used here - and the added 5 just indicates that I started collecting data on a Friday.

Surely this can be done more elegantly, but that's the best I have been able to come up with.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to use the date formatting commands for this. But if you were happy that the sequential integer labels were being generating correctly and just want to change the labels to day names, then it should work to use (gnuplot 5.2):

```
Array Day = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
label(x) = Day[ int(x/288. + 4) % 7 + 1]

plot "Data1" using ($1/288):2:xticlabel(label($1)) title "First Data Set" with lines, \
     "Data2" using ($1/288):2 title "Second Data Set" with lines
```

If your gnuplot is too old to support arrays, you could use instead (gnuplot 5.0):

```
Week = "Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday"
label(x) = word(Week, (int(x/288. + 4) % 7) + 1)

plot "Data1" using ($1/288):2:xticlabel(label($1)) title "First Data Set" with lines, \
     "Data2" using ($1/288):2 title "Second Data Set" with lines
```

The extra "+1" in the label function is because both arrays and strings in gnuplot number the elements starting from 1.

**Axis labels by day of week independent of data points**
Assuming input x values are in seconds, I think the easiest way of doing this is:

```
set xtics time format "%A"      # Name of day
set xtics 60. * 60. * 24.       # One tic per day
set xtics rotate by -45         # avoid crowding
plot "Data" using 1:2
```

You do ***not*** need `set xdata time` or `set timefmt`
Since the x values in your file are in units of 5 minutes (300 seconds) as I understand it, you would need to convert to seconds on input.

```
plot "Data" using ($1*300):2
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get your example to work though. Since I am using Gnuplot 5.0.3, I have no arrays - I therefore used the older version. Here, the definition of label(x) is missing a left parenthesis, which (it would seem) should go before int. The plot line seems to have a stray right square bracket. When I remove it I can plot my data, but I a get a thick black line in my x axis - no labels.

Comment: Sorry for the typos. The thick black line is probably made up of all the day names running on top of each other.  The commands I show will place a label for every single point. That's what I thought you asked for but maybe that's not what you really want?  If you want one label per day, independent of the actual data points, that's a rather different question.  Let me think about the easiest way to do that.

Comment: I tried with the 'set xtics time format "%A"...' block, and it seems to do most of what I need, much more elegantly than my approach. Thank you. I notice that, when converted to seconds, the values for the x axis are taken to be the number of seconds since the Epoch - which fits well what I want to do, by adding the appropriate number of seconds at plotting time.